# Firefox Addon won't open new tab with url

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I tried this code:

```
var contextMenu = require("context-menu");
var menuItem = contextMenu.Item({
  label: "Test name",
  contentScript:  'self.on("click", function () {' + 
                  '  window.open("options.html", "_blank");' +
                  '});'
});
```

But when I click on the new Context menu item, I get the following error:

> Security Error: Content at *"le Site"* may not load or link to chrome://browser/content/options.html.

Which permissions do I have to give of get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the relative address is resolved incorrectly in case of a content script - as a result you are attempting to open `chrome://browser/content/options.html` in a window which is correctly forbidden. Simply specify the full address and things should work:

```js
'  window.open("http://example.com/options.html", "_blank");' +
```

Comment: If this is supposed to enter a page from the data folder in your add-on, you should first get the resource uri for the html page by using self.data.url('options.html') and then include this in the content script string.